# New Site Design Launched!

Tags: discussion, design, site-promotion

[image: Dance Dance Dance]

Congratulations! As you can see, the new site design just went live.

Later this week a themed the Twitter account, newsletter template, and chat room will be made for the community based off of this design. Also reputation levels have been adjusted as well.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with **design** and **bug**.

Congrats again and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: Many thanks Joshua! Will hammer on it for bugs etc, but it looks lovely!

Comment: Very happy... and a little disturbed by the dancing tigers...

Comment: Love it! Great job! =)

Comment: What a nice surprise :)